# trying to run rasberry pi on qemu says -redir invalid option

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu, raspbian

I am trying to run Rasberry Pi on `qemu` but it says `-redir` invalid option.

Here's my command:

```shell
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append “root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash” -drive “file=2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw” -redir tcp:2222::22
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a correct error message. There is no such option. [It was removed in release 3.1 of Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/about/removed-features.html#redir-removed-in-3-1).

From https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/about/removed-features.html

> `-redir` (removed in 3.1)
>
> The `-redir [tcp|udp]:hostport:[guestaddr]:guestport` option is replaced by either `-netdev user,id=x,hostfwd=[tcp|udp]:[hostaddr]:hostport-[guestaddr]:guestport` (for pluggable NICs, accompanied with `-device ...,netdev=x`) or by the option `-nic user,hostfwd=[tcp|udp]:[hostaddr]:hostport-[guestaddr]:guestport` (for on-board NICs). The new syntax allows different settings to be provided per NIC.